# Multiple configuration providers with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I specify multiple providers to AngularJS?

Right now I'm doing it in 2 places, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

  // route for the home page
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
    controller  : 'aboutController'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
    controller  : 'contactController'
  });
```

});

```
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((').endSymbol('))');
}
);
```

Comment: Be precise. "That doesn't seem to work" doesn't help us identifying what the problem is. What happens precisely? Do you have any error? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use a single function reference:

```
myApp.config(foo)
```

which injects each provider:

```
function foo($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) 
 {     
 /* interpolateProvider configuration */
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((').endSymbol('))');

 /* routeProvider configuration */
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
    controller  : 'aboutController'
  })
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
    controller  : 'contactController'
  });
 }

/* module creation */
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

/* provider binding */
myApp.config(foo);

/* Manual bootstrapping */
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

 /* $inject Property Annotation */
 foo.$inject['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider'];
```

> Providers are essentially objects that are used to create and configure instances of AngularJS artefacts. Hence, in order to register a lazy controller, you would use the $controllerProvider. Similarly, To register a directive, you would use the $compileProvider, to register filters you would use the $filterProvider, and to register other services, you would use the $provide service.

**References**

- [AngularJS: Configuration Blocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#configuration-blocks)
- [AngularJS: Inject Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di?_escaped_fragment_=#-inject-property-annotation)

Comment: To inject it should be `foo.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider'];`